# ReactNative: View config not found for name li

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I have no idea about this error, Can anyone help on this.
React Native application.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
react-native link
```

Seems like your libraries are not linked correctly. You can check links by doing below steps in android side.

1. Check android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java. All of your linked libraries should be there. If not follow below steps (But you should have a clear idea about linked module)

   - Add import com.........Package; to the imports at the top of the file
   - Add new ReactNative.........Package() to the list returned by the getPackages() method
   - Add new ReactNative...........Package(MainActivity.class) to he list returned by the getPackages()method instead.
2. check whether the following lines are available in android/settings.gradle if not add it for link libraries

   - include ':react-native-...........'
   - project(':react-native-...........').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,
     '../node_modules/react-native-....your module path/androd')
3. Check whether the following lines are available in inside the dependencies block in android/app/build.gradle. if not add it to link libraries.

   - compile project(':react-native-....yourpackage npm name')

**Please be careful if you have no idea about linked modules**.

When you run above 'react-native link' command, there will be some duplicate code segments in the above three files (only if some linked module not configured correctly). If there are any duplicate remove those as well.

Comment: am using the Mac and iOS Simulator.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios you can get an idea about the link modules manually for ios by browsing this.

Comment: Yes i try react-native link, I got error "rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null"